# A problem on rectilinear motion in a car

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, time

Today, I attempted the third question in the first chapter (*Physical Fundamentals of Mechanics*) in the book [Problems in General Physics by I. E. Irodov](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8123902514). The question goes like this:

> A car starts moving rectilinearly, first with acceleration $\omega=5.0\ ms^{-2}$ (the initial velocity is equal to zero), then uniformly, and finally, decelerating at the same rate $\omega$, comes to a stop. The total time of motion equals $\tau=25\ s$. The average velocity during that time is equal to $\langle v\rangle=72\ km\ h^{-1}$. How long does the car move uniformly?

Here's how I solved the problem.

First of all, I drew the velocity-time graph describing the motion of the car, which I provide below:

[image: Velocity-time graph]

### While accelerating,

Initial velocity $(u)=0$
Acceleration $(a)=\omega$

Assuming the time interval to be $t_0$, we get

Final velocity $(v)=u+at$
$$or,\: v=0+\omega t_0$$
$$or,\: t_0=\frac{v}{\omega}\tag{1}$$

### While decelerating,

Initial velocity $(u)=v$
Acceleration $(a)=-\omega$

Assuming the time interval to be $t_2$, we get

Final velocity $(v)=u+at$
$$or,\: 0=v-\omega t_1$$
$$or,\: t_1=\frac{v}{\omega}$$
$$or,\: t_1=t_0\ [from\ (1)]$$

Now, if the car travels with uniform velocity for a time $t_1$, then we have,
$$\tau=2t_0+t_1=25\ s\tag{2}$$

We know, average velocity $\langle v\rangle=\frac{total\ displacement}{total\ time}$
$$or,\: \langle v\rangle=\frac{S}{\tau}$$
$$or,\: \frac{72\times 5}{18}=\frac{S}{25}$$
$$or,\: S=500\ m$$

Moreover, $S=Area\ under\ the\ graph$
$$or,\: 500=\frac{1}{2}vt_0+vt_1+\frac{1}{2}vt_2$$
$$or,\: v(t_0+t_1)=500$$
$$or,\: v(\tau-t_0)=500$$
$$or,\: \omega t_0(25-t_0)=500$$
$$or,\: t_0^2-25t_0+100=0$$

Solving it, we get $t_0=5\ s$ as $t_0\neq 20\ s\ (t_0 < \frac{25}{2}\ s)$

### **Hence, $t_1=25-2\times 5\ s=15\ s$**

After putting a lot of effort I find that my perseverance has paid off: *I got the correct answer.* But thing which I saw on the answer page made me feel that I am an idiot:

> $$\Delta t=\tau \sqrt{1-4\langle v \rangle/\omega t}=15\ s$$

It seems as though my approach is unnecessarily lengthy. What I do not understand is:

***How did the author arrive at that ridiculously simple expression?***

Also, I would like to know if there any more terse or concise approaches to questions like this.

Comment: It looks like he may have just done exactly the working you did, just without putting in numbers until the end (i.e. his expression looks like the solution to a quadratic, just as in your working)

Comment: @Zephyr Yes, but how could he have disregarded the invalid value (i.e. the other root) for $\Delta t$?

Comment: or alternatively, notice the average velocity during the acceleration periods is omega*t0/2, call the steady velocity u, hence omega*t0*t0+v*t1=72 (average velocity) and omega*t0=v (total velocity) and 2*t0 + t1 =T (total time). I haven't worked this through and about to run out the door but seems like it should work.

Comment: *how could he have disregarded the invalid value* Does "Because he knew the answer before writing it down & is only interested in showing you the *right* answer without bothering to show the *wrong* one." count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get that answer by noticing that in when you have constant acceleration the average velocity after a time $t$ is:

\begin{equation}
\langle v\rangle_{acc.=w}=\frac{v_{start}+(v_{start}+w t)}{2}
\end{equation}

for your case $v_{start}=0$ and then $\langle v\rangle_{acc.=w}=\frac{wt}{2}$. For the deceleration we get the same result.

Now you can write 
\begin{align}
\langle v\rangle\cdot\tau&=\underbrace{\frac{w t}{2}}_{\langle v\rangle_{acceleration}} t
+ \underbrace{w t}_{v_{uniform}}
\underbrace{(\tau -2 t)}_{=:\Delta t}
+\underbrace{\frac{w t}{2}}_{\langle v\rangle_{deceleration}} t\\
&=wt\left( t + \Delta t\right) ,
\end{align}
where $\Delta t$ is the time you are looking for.
You can easily write $2t=\tau-\Delta t$ in the last equation and then solve:
\begin{equation}
\langle v\rangle\cdot\tau=\frac{w}{4}(\tau^2-\Delta t^2)
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\Delta t=\tau\sqrt{1-\frac{4\langle v\rangle}{w\tau}}
\end{equation}